# Bot in Teams freeze

Tags: botframework

I often experience that bots in Microsoft Teams freeze - they simply stop reponding. They still responds in other channels like Skype and Web. After a few hours they start responding again. Any help or input is appreciated.

SDK 4.0

Comment: Hello Thomas, unfortunately it will be impossible to give help on that kind of topic here

Comment: Are you still running into this issue? If so, can you provide more information (e.g. language, state store being used, code) about your bot's setup and details about the timeframe of the observed behavior?